# How to use bearer token for authorization for POST method in sync-request?

Tags: node.js

How can we use bearer token with POST method using npm sync-request? The sync-request resource page has the way to use authorization in GET request but not in POST request.

```
*******GET Request*******
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('GET', 'https://example.com', {
'headers': {
'user-agent': 'example-user-agent'
}
});

****POST Request*****
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('POST', 'https://example.com/create-user', {
  json: { username: 'Name' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to use `sync-request` which can cause timing issues but this should work with either `sync-request` or `request`

```js
// *******GET Request*******
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('GET', 'https://example.com', {
  'headers': {
    'user-agent': 'example-user-agent',
    'authorization', 'Bearer ' + authId
  }
});


// ****POST Request*****
var request = require('sync-request');
var res = request('POST', 'https://example.com/create-user', {
  'headers': {
    'authorization', 'Bearer ' + authId
  },
  json: { username: 'Name' }
});
```

`authId` needs to be whatever your bearer token spoils be for your app.

Comment: I used sync-request to call my services in an order. I have updated the code like but still not working.                                                                              
 var res = request('POST', ep,{
    'headers': {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token,
  }}, {
    json: payment_info_data
});
    var user = JSON.parse(res.getBody('utf8'));

Comment: Can you post the error message and a description of exactly what is failing?

Comment: I used authorization and now I am getting unexplained 500 error. I think it is not possible to use authorization in POST request in sync-request module. So i switched to use 'request' module and it is working out. Thanks@Intervalia

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use of axis and example below:-
***GET***

> import axios from "axios";

```
 axios({
        method: 'get',
        url: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
      console.log(response);
    }).catch((err) => {
       console.log(err)
      ));
```

***POST***

```
             axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: url,
                    data: JSON.stringify({orders}),
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': userObj.token
                    }
                }).then(function (response) {
                     console.log(response)
                });
```

Where ubserObj.token -

> Bearer Token ex: ***Bearer ASDF@!@#!ADFASDF!@#!@#***

This will be on the server side settings.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. Now I am using request module instead of sync-request module.